# How to output user input in a different webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am setting up a website for ordering pizza and want to be able to output the user's orders on the checkout page. I need to know which image the user clicked, each image is a different pizza. The sauce is working perfectly because I can use a form with a submit button, however for the OnlinePizzaOrderingPage.html I cannot use a submit button. I have included the sql tag below because sql is allowed to be used, however I don't know if it will help in this scenario. How do I achieve display the type of pizza the user selected on the ShoppingCart.php page?

I have tried using POST and GET with php and using Javascript.

OnlinePizzaOrderingPage.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Online Pizza Ordering Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    <script>
    function imageTitle(title){
     alert(title);
     console.log(title);
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Online Pizza Ordering Page</h1>
    <a href="Detailedsauceandquantitypage.html"><img src="supreme.jpg" 
    width="82" height="86" title="Supreme" alt="Supreme" 
    onclick="imageTitle(this.title);"></a>
    <a href="Detailedsauceandquantitypage.html"><img src="meatlover.jpg" 
    width="82" height="86" title="Meatlover" alt="Meatlover" 
    onclick="imageTitle(this.title);"></a>
    <a href="Detailedsauceandquantitypage.html"><img src="hawaii.jpg" 
    width="82" height="86" title="Hawaii" alt="Hawaii" 
    onclick="imageTitle(this.title);"></a>
    <a href="Detailedsauceandquantitypage.html"><img 
src="fourseasons.jpg" 
    width="82" height="86" title="Four Seasons" alt="Four Seasons" 
    onclick="imageTitle(this.title);"></a>
    <a href="Detailedsauceandquantitypage.html"><img src="vege.jpg" 
width="82" 
    height="86" title="Vege" alt="Vege" 
onclick="imageTitle(this.title);"></a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

DetailedSauceandquantitypage.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="script.js"></script>
            <title>Detailed sauce and quantity page</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Detailed sauce and quantity page</h1>
                <form action="ShoppingCartpage.php" method="POST">
                    <img src="bbq.jpg" alt="BBQ">
                    <label for="numberOfSauces">Number of Pizzas 
    (0-100):</label>
                    <input type="number" name="bbqPizza" min="0" 
    max="100" value="0"><br>
                    <img src="tomato.jpg" alt="Tomato">
                    <label for="numberOfSauces">Number of Pizzas 
   (0-100):</label>
                    <input type="number" name="tomatoPizza" 
    min="0" max="100" value="0"><br>
                    <img src="salsa.jpg" alt="Salsa">
                    <label for="numberOfSauces">Number of Pizzas 
    (0-100):</label>
                    <input type="number" name="salsaPizza" min="0" 
    max="100" value="0"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" 
    name="submit"><br>
                </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

ShoppingCartpage.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Shopping Cart page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    <script>
    function imageTitle(title){
     alert(title);
     console.log(title);
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Shopping Cart page</h1>
    <?php
    // define variables and set to empty values
    $bbqPizza = $tomatoPizza = $salsaPizza = "";

    if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
        $bbq = $_POST["bbqPizza"];
        $tomato = $_POST["tomatoPizza"];
        $salsa = $_POST["salsaPizza"];
        echo $bbq . " pizzas with bbq sauce, " . $tomato . " pizzas with 
    tomato sauce and " . $salsa . " pizzas with salsa sauce.";
    }
    ?>
    <br>
    <a href="OnlinePizzaOrderingPage.html">Add more pizzas to cart</a>
    <a href="Checkoutpage.html">Go to checkout</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Expected results are the pizza type selected by the user through clicking the images on OnlinePizzaOrderingPage.html to be displayed on the ShoppingCart.php page.

Comment: Actually stuck, no idea what I should do.

Comment: I also tried putting the image inside a submit button but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.html` has no native way of retrieving or storing request values (post/get) that can then be passed to a PHP file. You would need to change `DetailedSauceandquantitypage.html` to to a PHP page, and use a querystring in *OnlinePizzaOrderingPage.html* to determine which link was clicked on, such as `href="DetailedSauceandquantitypage.php?pizza=Supreme"`.

> As was mentioned in a previous question you made, you should seriously
>   consider converting all of your `.html` files to `.php`, to avoid
>   having make a ton of changes later, when you want to expand your
>   application files to use php code.

For more details please see [*Variables From External Sources*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php)

If you are using Apache web server you could use [`SSI` (server side includes)](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html), but as you are using PHP, it would be a lot simpler and less error prone to convert to PHP instead.

Example:

I removed some of the javascript for brevity. I am also not sure how you would like to be able to add on to or checkout the current order, aside from storing it in a database.

*OnlinePizzaOrderingPage.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Online Pizza Ordering Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Online Pizza Ordering Page</h1>
    <a href="Detailedsauceandquantitypage.php?pizza=supreme">
        <img src="supreme.jpg" width="82" height="86" title="Supreme" alt="Supreme">
    </a>
    <a href="Detailedsauceandquantitypage.php?pizza=meatlover">
        <img src="meatlover.jpg" width="82" height="86" title="Meatlover" alt="Meatlover">
    </a>
    <a href="Detailedsauceandquantitypage.php?pizza=hawaii">
        <img src="hawaii.jpg" width="82" height="86" title="Hawaii" alt="Hawaii">
    </a>
    <a href="Detailedsauceandquantitypage.php?pizza=fourseasons">
        <img src="fourseasons.jpg" width="82" height="86" title="Four Seasons" alt="Four Seasons">
    </a>
    <a href="Detailedsauceandquantitypage.php?pizza=vege">
        <img src="vege.jpg" width="82" height="86" title="Vege" alt="Vege">
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

*DetailedSauceandquantitypage**.php***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Detailed sauce and quantity page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Detailed sauce and quantity page</h1>
    <form action="ShoppingCartpage.php" method="POST">
        <!-- set form value to retrieve and pass the selected pizza to the cart -->
        <input type="hidden" name="pizza" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['pizza'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false); ?>">

        <img src="bbq.jpg" alt="BBQ">
        <label for="numberOfSauces">Number of Pizzas (0-100):</label>
        <input type="number" name="bbqPizza" min="0" max="100" value="0">
        <br>
        <img src="tomato.jpg" alt="Tomato">
        <label for="numberOfSauces">Number of Pizzas (0-100):</label>
        <input type="number" name="tomatoPizza" min="0" max="100" value="0"> 
        <br>
        <img src="salsa.jpg" alt="Salsa">
        <label for="numberOfSauces">Number of Pizzas (0-100):</label>
        <input type="number" name="salsaPizza" min="0" max="100" value="0"> 
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" name="submit">
        <br>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

*ShoppingCartpage.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Shopping Cart page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Shopping Cart page</h1>
    <?php
    // define variables and set to empty values
    $bbqPizza = $tomatoPizza = $salsaPizza = "";

    if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
        $pizza = $_POST['pizza']; //value from first page
        $bbq = $_POST["bbqPizza"];
        $tomato = $_POST["tomatoPizza"];
        $salsa = $_POST["salsaPizza"];
        echo "A " . $pizza . " pizza, " .  $bbq . " pizzas with bbq sauce, " . $tomato . " pizzas with tomato sauce and " . $salsa . " pizzas with salsa sauce.";

       //where are these stored to Add More or Checkout?
    }
    ?>
    <br>
    <a href="OnlinePizzaOrderingPage.html">Add more pizzas to cart</a>
    <a href="Checkoutpage.html">Go to checkout</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried converting them all to php and then deleting all the html files but then the website said object not found if I do that.

Comment: You need to update your links, form actions, and redircts as well. You should only need to rename the files from `.html` to `.php` Then update any `<form action="****.html">` or `<a href="*****.html">` or `header('location: ****.html')`  to use `.php` instead.

Comment: <?php /* 
        Retrieve previous page pizza selection to pass to cart 
        */ ?> How do I do that without a form? You said to use the href thing but isn't href for creating a link user can click on like <a href="..."></a>.

Comment: The `input` with the `<?php echo $_GET['pizza']; ?>` code below that comment is doing so. The `href` in the previous snippet includes the querystring `?pizza=` on all of the links.  `htmlspecialchars` is used to prevent malicious uses of the querystring.

Comment: But that only puts the input into Detailedsauceandquantitypage.php. I need to print the name of the chosen pizza on ShoppingCartpage.php.

Comment: I covered that also in the answer, the hidden input field submits the selected value to `ShoppingCartpage.php`, and I added the `$_POST['pizza']` to be displayed in the first portion of your `echo` statement

Comment: I added         <input type="hidden" name="pizza" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['pizza'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false); ?>">
how do I check whether it is working or not? I changed input type to text and it came up with an undefined index error.

Comment: <br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: pizza in <b>C:\Program Files (x86)\XAMPP\htdocs\Detailedsauceandquantitypage.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />

Comment: You have have to click on one of the links in my `OnlinePizzaOrderingPage.html` example  or navigate to `DetailedSauceandquantitypage.php?pizza=a_pizza_name`

Comment: Alright that works so far. If I were to allow a user to add more pizzas to the cart, after I press the add more to cart. The webpage changes to the OnlinePizzaOrderingpage.html, however once I go through the process again, the previous order is overwritten. How do I prevent losing the previous order? So then I can make it create a new line and write the second pizza under the first pizza.

Comment: That's why I added the comment "*where are these stored to Add More or Checkout?*", you would need to use a Database (SQL), `COOKIES` or `SESSION` to store the submitted values behind the scenes or pass them as variables in your other links. But that is outside of the scope of this particular question and suggest asking a separate one on how to retain those values during multiple submissions.